Can we create python project into .dll for using in c#
Can we create python project into .dll for using in c#.
I tried using PyInstaller, which only creates .exe files. In my Python project, I use multiple external packages such as OpenCV and Pandas.
Although I successfully created an .exe file for the Python project, when called from C#, I'm not getting any results; it returns null.
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed math_operation.py
#this commed give math_opeartion.exe file
PYTHON math_opeartion.py
class A:

    def add(self,a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(self,a, b):
        return a - b
    

   
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Path to the .exe file
        string exePath = @"D:\math_operations\math_operations.exe";

        // Call the add function
        int result1 = CallPythonFunction(exePath, "add", 3, 4);
        Console.WriteLine($"The sum of 3 and 4 is: {result1}");

        // Call the subtract function
        int result2 = CallPythonFunction(exePath, "subtract", 10, 6);
        Console.WriteLine($"The difference between 10 and 6 is: {result2}");
    }

    static int CallPythonFunction(string exePath, string functionName, int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        // Start the process
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{functionName} {arg1} {arg2}";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();

        // Wait for the process to exit
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Get the output from the process
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        // Check for errors
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:");
            Console.WriteLine(error);
            return 0;
        }

        // Convert the output to an integer and return it
        return int.Parse(output.Trim());
    }
}


How do you need those to interact? Maybe it's enough to just put a database in the middle? OpenCV and pandas sounds like number crunching to me...

You can use Python.NET to embed your python code in C#. With this nuget package you can run python functions and instantiate Python classes directly in your C# code. See the pythonnet docs for more information and examples. I guess you can run python inside your CallPythonFunction en get the data you need from your python scripts.

How can I run an EXE file from my C# code?
In this post, there is an answer about running/invoking executables from C#. If you want to process data using your python script, you can change your script into outputting these data in a file, in some format (such as .json or .txt or .csv) and then, after the python processes has finished running, you can read them in C# using a stream reader or an appropriate file parser (https://www.bytehide.com/blog/streamreader-csharp).
Alternatively, you can check out pipelining text in CMD, and pipeline the output of one executable (which would be either stdout or stderr) to your C# program (https://superuser.com/questions/189362/how-to-pipe-command-output-to-other-commands).

The requirement is to convert the Python project into a .dll for use in C#. I believe converting the entire project is not possible unless the Python code is converted into C++. Therefore, I have decided to convert the .exe file and use it in C#.

@user24257486 that might not be a viable option, so I wouldn't recommend to deprive yourself of options. And a out-of-process solution doesn't sound far fetched considering the variety of dependencies. Of course you can do GPU-Computing from C# but I personally don't know if there is a feature-equivalent to pandas. And you just don't "convert" a python app as easily to a managed dotnet library as you might think.  Not to start about efficiency...

The requirement is simply not probable
